# Naive Bayes category keywords

Tags: nlp, tf-idf, naivebayes

I'm using multinomial Naive Bayes to sort documents into three categories. I would like to find the most important 'keywords' of each category, akin to using tf-idf to find the keywords of a document. I have attempted to use tf-idf for each document in the corpus and getting some overall keyword lists for each category based on the keywords of documents within those categories, but I can't find a good way to combine all these keyword lists. I have also thought about treating each category itself as a single, massive 'document' and getting the keywords using tf-idf, but this doesn't give very great results when you only have three such 'documents'.

**Is there a known/common method for getting category keywords?**

Comment: You can try `LDA`. Please put more context.

Comment: I already have the categories defined, so `LDA` is unnecessary. I want to know after classifying documents how to find a list of words that are the most important / characteristic in each category.